# Bootstrap grid inside a TD

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a column that holds grid-like data in a single TD:

1   $1,234.56

2   $2,000.00

11 $8,000.00

Rather than specifying a table inside of the TD, I've attempted to use the Bootstrap 3 grid classes. This worked great when my table was small, but adding the grid to a larger table (with more columns) is behaving differently. When the table has too many columns, my two column grid within the TD is wrapping and looks like a one column grid like so:

1
$1,234.56
2
$2,000.00
11
$8,000.00

The code I'm using is similar to this, though needs more columns to witness the problem. Full [JSFiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jqagz9nc/)

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header for 2 column grid</th>
    </tr>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some content
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">1,234.56</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">13</div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">8,000.00</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion to preserve my two column grid in my TD, using Bootstrap or otherwise?

Comment: _Rather than specifying a table inside of the TD, I've attempted to use the Bootstrap 3 grid classes._ Why? This looks like tabular data.

Comment: I've traditionally used nested tables for layout, but I'm trying to expand my horizons. Yes, this column holds tabular data, but it didn't seem appropriate to use the full weight of a table in every single row  for a two column grid. I've been exploring semantic classes and am trying to define a generic structure to handle the simple "key: value" scenario that we sometimes encounter in our tables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change your HTML to

```
    <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">1,000.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">1,582.99</div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

and add this line to your CSS:

```
.row .col-xs-2, .row .col-xs-10{display:inline-block; float: none}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9jeyyfdL/)

Comment: Ooh, this looks like it will do the trick. Thanks for your help Fabio!

Answer (score 1):

Change `col-sm-...` to `col-xs-...`.

But @George Cummins' suggestion  should also be considered.

Comment: Thanks. I did give this a shot, but unfortunately that didn't quite get me there either.

Answer (score 0):

As George has said I'd use only bootstrap classes,

use `container` (or custom wrap) instead of `table`,

`rows` for `tr` ,

and finally you divide your rows in columns (`col-sm-2` - `col-sm-10`) instead of `td` (or `th`)

Comment: I do prefer to continue to use the table for the broader tabular data, as there are other styles and goodness that go along with it that I'd like to continue to leverage.

Comment: well that makes sense , anyway remember bootstrap class are more oriented to responsiveness (widths are set with %),

Comment: Thanks maioman. Yes, I'm pretty new to the whole Bootstrap thing and am just starting to get the hang of it, so I do appreciate the reminder and the pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
td .row { margin-right: 0 !important; }
```